# Too many ifs with image background changing?

Tags: android, image, if-statement, background, many-to-many

I'm making an android app with many images inside. I have to change background of 30 images inside my app due to a variable which i read from shared preferences. It looks like that (only a part witch background changing, ofc I write "findviewvbyid" and read shared preferences data:

```
if (fav[0]==0) s0.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s0.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[1]==0) s1.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[2]==0) s2.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[3]==0) s3.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s3.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[4]==0) s4.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s4.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[5]==0) s5.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s5.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[6]==0) s6.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s6.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[7]==0) s7.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s7.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[8]==0) s8.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s8.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[9]==0) s9.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s9.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);    
if (fav[10]==0) s0.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s0.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[11]==0) s1.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[12]==0) s2.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[13]==0) s3.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s3.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[14]==0) s4.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s4.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[15]==0) s5.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s5.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[16]==0) s6.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s6.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[17]==0) s7.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s7.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[18]==0) s8.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s8.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[19]==0) s9.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s9.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[20]==0) s0.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s0.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[21]==0) s1.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[22]==0) s2.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[23]==0) s3.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s3.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[24]==0) s4.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s4.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[25]==0) s5.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s5.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[26]==0) s6.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s6.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[27]==0) s7.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s7.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[28]==0) s8.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s8.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[29]==0) s9.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s9.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        if (fav[30]==0) s9.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara); else s9.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
```

I noticed that everything works fine with 10 variables, every amount above is not working. Thanks for the help

Comment: in what way is it not working? Are you running out of memory?..

Comment: No, there's no change in background image, till 10 variables eveything works fine, over 10 nothing change

Comment: is fav[30] supposed to change s9, or does it change s0?

Comment: @CBredlow - thanks, silly mistake, every variable from fav[10] is changing wrong s number ;)